# How can i to do a link to a specific date in Datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to make adatepicker for my site,
I have found this Datepicker heres a link http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

How can i to do a link for aspecific date For example on 10/03/2017 date?

--
Edit:
how i can to do like- link http://int.soccerway.com/
in the right side?
I want pretty much like the this adate picker with link abuot every day.

And again, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

-- Edit: how i can to do like- link http://int.soccerway.com/ in the right side? I want pretty much like the this adate picker with link abuot every day.

And again, thank you :)